# PrimeNG angular datatable loading an array of strings

Tags: angular, primeng

I'm new to the PrimeNG Datatable grid.  Originally my grid had properties that tied in nicely with the grid:

```
                            <p-column
                                field="ColShortName"
                                header="Select a Column"
                                [sortable]="true"
                                [filter]="true"
                                filterPlaceholder="Search"
                                filterMatchMode="contains"
                            >
                            </p-column>
```

However now I change the underlying Data Array to JUST be an array of strings:

["Component.O_Account_Period","Component.O_Account_Period_Commencement_Date",..]

Now in my grid I see a bunch of empty rows as it is reading the data, but I don't know what to replace the field with?

What if my array doesn't have any properties?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="form-group col-xs-12">
    <p-dataTable
        appAutoFocus
        [value]="columnDefinitionData"
        sortMode="multiple"
        [multiSortMeta]="multiSortMeta"
        [scrollable]="true"
        scrollHeight="150px"
        (onRowSelect)="onEdit($event)"
        selectionMode="single"
        [(selection)]="selectedItem"
    >
        <p-column
            header="Select a Column"
            [sortable]="true"
            [filter]="true"
            filterPlaceholder="Search"
            filterMatchMode="contains"
        ></p-column>
    </p-dataTable>
</div>
```

**.ts:**

```
public columnDefinitionData: string[] = [];

private loadColumnDefinitions() {
    this._directUpdateService.getColumnDefs().subscribe(
        r => {
            this.columnDefinitionData = r;
            for (let i = 0; i <= this.logs.length - 1; i++) {
                if (
                    this.logs[i].wfWorkflowStatus ===
                        "CDS2 Validation Failed" ||
                    this.logs[i].wfWorkflowStatus === "Ready for Review"
                ) {
                    this._disableAdd = false;
                }
            }
        },
        e => {
            throw e;
        }
    );
}
```

**service.ts:**

```
public getColumnDefs(): Observable<string[]> {
    return this._http.get(`${this._columnDefinitionUrl}GetDbTableCDS2`);
}
```

As you can see the grid is being populated with rows, but the data is not being presented.  I also need this to be searchable.  When I was using an object I was able to search.

[image]

Comment: Can you post the full html and ts file? You have shared only the column part, where are you assigning the data?

Comment: @Niladri - Let me know if more info is needed.